# Catch ALL dispatched events in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React and Electron. I want to save the entire state to local storage when the user updates it. Right now, I can do something like this on each reducer.

```
const savedUsers = window.localStorage.getItem('users');

export default function users(state={
  fetching: false,
  data: savedUsers ? JSON.parse(savedUsers) : []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ....
    case RECEIVE_USERS:
      window.localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(action.data));
      return Object.assign(state, {
        fetching: false,
        data: action.data
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, ideally, I want to catch ALL dispatched events and save the entire tree of the state in local storage.

```
// after dispatch
function saveState (state) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
}
```

Is this possible to do in react and redux?

Comment: Have you seen this project? https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-storage It seems like the type of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you sir